# propose new time by a meeting invitation - Location is not visible

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar

When I would like to propose a new time for a meeting invitation I received than I am only able to see the participants however not the location which was originally reserved.

So the meeting owner has to recheck if the location is available at the new proposed time.

Is it possible to change the setup that also the location is visible and not only the participants when doing a proposal for a new meeting time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid there is no built-in option available in Outlook to see the availability of the location in the proposing new time window.
Normally there are multiple attendees in a meeting, and the organizer may receive more than one new time proposal messages for the meeting. So it seems that this is inevitable for the organizer to recheck the location before sending out the final update of the meeting.

Anyway, if you still have concern on such a feature, you may share your idea in [the Outlook UserVoice forum](https://outlook.uservoice.com/).